# How to check optional inputs?

Tags: knime

I've been searching the web for hours and can't seem to find a hint on how to actually handle optional input ports in my NodeModel's `execute` function. According to the documentation, `inData` is never `null` nor contains `null` values.

So how do I check whether an optional input port is connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just an artifact in the documentation from the -distant- past, when there were no optional inputs in KNIME. Currently for missing inputs, you will see `null` values in the `inData` array.

Comment: It worth noting that this part documentation will be updated before the next (2.12) release of KNIME. Thank you @scenia for bringing attention to this problem.